# How to combine two pandas series which are differently indexed?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to combine two differently indexed series together (same number of rows). I tried `pd.concat((s1, s2), axis=1)`.
For example, s1 is:

```
index | s1
----- | -----
0     | 1.5
----- | -----
1     | 2
```

and s2 is:

```
index | s2
----- | -----
a     | 1
----- | -----
b     | 2
```

but I get:

```
index | s1  | s2  
----- | --- | --- 
0     | 1.5 | NaN
----- | --- | ---
1     | 2   | NaN
----- | --- | ---
a     | NaN | 1
----- | --- | ---
b     | NaN | 2
```

What I want is:

```
index | s1  | s2 
----- | --- | ---
a     | 1.5 | 1
----- | --- | ---
b     | 2   | 2
```

That is keep the index of series2.
How could I get this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set index of `s1` by `s2` index first:

```
s1.index = s2.index
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
print (df)
    s1  s2
a  1.5   1
b  2.0   2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the index of s1 by s2's index and then concat them

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame({'s1':[1.5,2]},index=[0,1])
s2 = pd.DataFrame({'s2':[1,2]},index=['a','b'])
pd.concat([s2,s1.set_index(s2.index)],axis=1)
```

Output :

```
   s2   s1
a   1  1.5
b   2  2.0
```

or

```
pd.concat([s1.set_index(s2.index),s2],axis=1)
```

```
    s1  s2
a  1.5   1
b  2.0   2
```

Comment: While I know that Series objects do not provide the `set_index()` method, is there a difference between using `s1.set_index(s2.index)`  and `s1.index = s2.index` for two DataFrames?

Comment: @mylynn no there is no big difference but the s1.index =...  Will change the index in the s1 dataframe while set index above won't change anything inplace

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
[**`pd.DataFrame.insert`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

```
s2.insert(0, 's1', s1.s1.values)
s2

    s1  s2
a  1.5   1
b  2.0   2
```

---

**Option 2**
Reconstruct

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(s1=s1.s1.values, s2=s2.s2.values), s2.index)

    s1  s2
a  1.5   1
b  2.0   2
```

---

**Option 3**
[**`pd.DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
s1.set_index(s2.index).join(s2)

    s1  s2
a  1.5   1
b  2.0   2
```