# How to concatenate dataframe and series with different index

Tags: python, pandas

if I have one dataframe and series like these

```
  bi            sm
0  A          0  a
1  B          1  b
2  C          2  C
```

I can concatenate like this

```
dfA['sm'] = dfB

  big  sm
0 A    a
1 B    b 
2 C    c
```

However I have one dataframe and seriese, each has the different index but same row numbers.

```
            bi            sm
2017-11-04  A          0  a
2017-11-03  B          1  b
2017-11-02  C          2  C
```

I would like to concatenate these two into this

```
            bi  sm
2017-11-04  A   a
2017-11-03  B   b
2017-11-02  C   C
```

How can I make it???

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two pandas series which are differently indexed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475368/how-to-combine-two-pandas-series-which-are-differently-indexed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make both dataframes have the same index, then concatenate:

```
pd.concat([dfA, dfB.set_index(dfA.index)], axis=1)
#           bi sm
#2017-11-04  A  a
#2017-11-03  B  b
#2017-11-02  C  c
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Is it possible to   change the name of column when concatenating?? `sm` -> `md`

Comment: @whitebear Use `pd.concat([dfA, dfB.set_index(dfA.index)], axis=1).rename(columns={'sm' : 'md'})`

Comment: THank you, change index before concatinating is the very understandable.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign `dfB.sm` as values values

Option 1

```
In [209]: dfA['sm'] = dfB.sm.values

In [210]: dfA
Out[210]:
           bi sm
2017-11-04  A  a
2017-11-03  B  b
2017-11-02  C  C
```

Option 2

```
In [215]: dfA.assign(smm=dfB.sm.values)
Out[215]:
           bi smm
2017-11-04  A   a
2017-11-03  B   b
2017-11-02  C   C
```

Note: `dfA`, `dfB` are both dataframes.